# How pass command from file to dev-tools (ex chromium dev-tools)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I mean it,  i want write a simple script in a .js file to execute in the console of the dev tools (with the dev tools API), for example is a use the $ sign in the simple .js file to pass to the dev- tools (script in a html page ) i get error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined console.js:10
(anonymous function)
```

but in the dev-tools API, in the Chromium console it'll use to select the DOM element (selectByQuery()).

The problem is i can't understand how pass the script that it must be exec in the dev-tools console. How can i solve this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

look at example how load jquery library. Just execute this in console.  You can do similar with any script you need.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Hope, i understood you right

Comment: i mean it load the script in the dev-tools console !